# Animated collision not colliding with soft body

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I have a soft body object and a collision object, both are animated.

When the collision object collides with the softbody during the animation, nothing happens.

However, if I remove the animation from the collission and freely move it into the softbody, it collides as expected - so both are configured correctly from a physics perspective. It seems the animation on the collision is preventing it from colliding as expected, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the softbody physics were cached up to a certain frame by default - that was extremely misleading.